# Assembly language If and else statements

Tags: assembly, x86-16

How would i convert this to assembly?

given i have this menu

```
LEA SI, MSG1   
call PRINT_STRING    
gotoxy 0,1

LEA SI, MSG2  
call PRINT_STRING  
gotoxy 0,2

LEA SI, MSG3   
call PRINT_STRING  
gotoxy 0,3

LEA SI, MSG4  
call PRINT_STRING  
gotoxy 0,4    

LEA SI, MSG5  
call PRINT_STRING  
gotoxy 0,5
```

and define

```
MSG1 DB 'Choose Arithmetic Operation ' , 0  
MSG2 DB '(1) Addition ',0  
MSG3 DB '(2) Subtraction', 0  
MSG4 DB '(3) Multiplication',0  
MSG5 DB '(4) Division',0
```

DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS

and i want to insert this ifs'

if( x == 1)
then add
else if(x==2)
then subtract
else if(x==3)
then multiply
else if(x == 4)
then divide

given i have the functions for each arithmetic operation.

anybody ? i'm new to assembly and i find if and else statements weird at least if i learn the trick then it would be perfect. haha thanks by the way.

Comment: The simple solution: `cmp x, 1; je add; cmp x, 2; je subtract` and so on. Where did you get stuck ...

Answer (score 1):

For 8086 assembly, something like this:

```
    if(x == 1) {
        add();
    }
```

Would become something like this:

```
    cmp ax,1
    jne .skipIt
    call add
.skipIt:
```

It's like you can only do `if(something) goto somewhere` (where `goto` is the only thing you can have after the `if()`). Of course this gets messy when there's lots of branches (and on modern CPUs with branch mis-prediction penalties "many branches" can be much slower).

For your specific case (where the numbers are sequential); a smarter way would be to use a table. For example, something like this:

```
    switch(x) {
        case 0:
            add();
            break;
        case 1:
            sub();
            break;
    }
```

Could become this:

```
    section .data
myTable:
    dw add
    dw sub
    section .text

    cmp bx,2                ;Is BX too large?
    jae .l1                 ; yes, skip it
    add bx,bx               ;bx = bx * 2
    call [myTable+bx]       ;Call the address in the table
.l1:
```

Answer (score 1):

let me describe it with an example

For if(ax==bx) then ... :

```
CPM AX , BX ;COMPARE TO SET FLAGS
JMP THERE ;IF EQUAL THEN SKIP CORRECTION
THERE: MOV CL,07H
```

For if(ax!=bx) then ... :

```
CPM AX , BX ;COMPARE TO SET FLAGS
JNE THERE ;IF EQUAL THEN SKIP CORRECTION
THERE: MOV CL,07H
```

Also consider 2 points!

1- place your code (THERE: MOV CL,07H) after

```
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
```

2- choose a label for the rest of code to get back to where you've jumped from. like:

```
THERE: MOV CL,07H
JMP F:
```

Here is an example code:

```
    MOV AX,Data_here
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV AX,Stack_here
    MOV SS,AX  
    MOV x,05H
    MOV AL,x
    MOV BL,2H
    MOV AH,0
    DIV BL 
    CMP AH,00H
    JE L: 
  F:ADD AL,30H
    MOV AH,02H
    MOV DL,AL
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H    
    L: ADD AL,AH
    JMP F:
```

Comment: `jmp next_instruction` is a no-op, and not even conditional.  The first 2 code blocks in this are seriously broken, with the label in the wrong place and typoed instructions.